# Listing Google Drive File name, Permission level in the same call?

Tags: permissions, google-drive-api

Is there a way to list the google drive file name, and permission level in the same call?

I have been playing around with the Drive Api recently trying to do the following. 
I am trying to take a folder id and then get the permissions on that folder id. Then list out the child objects in that folder. 
I have been able to do that using the permission endpoint.

The problem I am seeing is when I list the children files in a folder, I only get the ids back. From there I run a loop over all those ids and then get my permission values back. But at that point there is no ID or File name in the result. 
I used the Drive V2 permissions list endpoint

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/list

Here is an example of the json output.

https://gist.github.com/daguy666/c90cd9e94ca3845b5aab

Things I would love to get out of this one call.

- User info (email / username)
- Permission level
- File name or File ID

Comment: Instead of permissions.list, try using files.list. In files.list, you can see list of all the files in your drive. If parent has children, you can see that list too. Also, you can see user information permission level with role_type reader/writer/owner), file id,permission id too. This method suits your use case.

Comment: I ended up figuring out earlier that if I used files.get  that provides all the info I need.
https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".